# MySQL SUM and MIN after each operation

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, recursive-query

Consider the following table structure:

```
|----------|-----------|----|
| Quantity | BaseValue | Id |
|----------|-----------|----|
|  -0.3    | 1         | 1  |
|  -0.8    | 1         | 2  |
|   0.5    | 1         | 3  |
|  -0.2    | 1         | 4  |
|----------|-----------|----|
```

Let's say this is a table, called `Transactions`. Is there any way to make a select query on this table, that will sum the values in the `Quantity` column, based on the following rule set:

- every row will be summed that has an `Id` that is less then **x**
- first, add `BaseValue` to a variable of a sort, let's call it **y**
- then for each row, add `Quantity` to **y**, and if the result is less then 0, **y** will be 0

The result I would like to see are something like this:

if **x** is 1, **y** should be **1**
if **x** is 2, **y** should be **0.7**
if **x** is 3, **y** should be **0**
if **x** is 4, **y** should be **0.5**

After a select operation I would like to see the following table for example:

```
|----------|-----------|----|-----|
| Quantity | BaseValue | Id | Y   |
|----------|-----------|----|-----|
|  -0.3    | 1         | 1  | 1   |
|  -0.8    | 1         | 2  | 0.7 |
|   0.5    | 1         | 3  | 0   |
|  -0.2    | 1         | 4  | 0.5 |
|----------|-----------|----|-----|
```

The MySQL version I am using is: `10.2.16-MariaDB`

**Example:**

Let's say **x** is 4, how the program should work is the following:

1. Y = BaseValue + 0
2. Get line with `Id=1`, sum together **Y** and `Quantity` from the line, the result is 0.7, because this is larger then 0, **Y** is now 0.7
3. Get line with `Id=2`, sum together **Y** and `Quantity` from the line, the result is -0.1, because this is lower then 0, **Y** is now 0
4. Get line with `Id=3`, sum together **Y** and `Quantity` from the line, the result is 0.5, this is larger then 0, so it stays
5. No more lines to take as `4 < x` is not true, so **Y** is 0.5

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using `10.2.16-MariaDB`

Comment: if X is 4 then Y should be 0.4 right?

Comment: no, if x is 4, y should be 0.5, because: y0 = 0 + baseValue = 1, y1 = y0 + q1 = 0.7, y2 = y1 + q2 = -0.1 which should be converted to 0, y3 = y2 + q3 = 0.5

Comment: Can you edit your question- put the working out there, where it might be clearer

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean by "put the working out there"?

Comment: based on your data sample which is the expected  result  ??

Comment: got it. This is interesting. Put these calculation to your question.

Comment: @scaisEdge it is written in the question

Comment: then is not clear to me ..  i don't see  a result for a select  .. i only see  a list of if x then  ...

Comment: @scaisEdge added a select result also

Comment: My head hurts :-(

Comment: @Strawberry   . mine  too..

Comment: is it so complicated, that I am causing pain to you guys?:( :)

Comment: @scaisEdge `x` is an input. List of `x` is where op shows what & how he wants to be the result for that particular input

Comment: this thing can work better if it's calculated by some programming/coding. Doing this with sql doesn't sound appropriate to me. Still i find it interesting & try to do it via sql

Comment: Basically what I want `Y` is to be in each line, is `Quantity` in the respective line, added to the `Y` of the previous line, maxed out. Y = MAX(PreviousY+CurrentQuantity, 0)

Comment: I could easily solve this in PHP, but that way I can't output the result in a tabled format, because my infrastructure prevents it, unfortunately, that's why I am looking for a single query solution:)

Comment: Seems a  procedural calculation and not a relational  .. so as suggested  should be done using server side programming code

Comment: That's GREATEST, not MAX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a recursive CTE based solution:

```
WITH RECURSIVE rcte AS (
    SELECT base.*, (SELECT 1.0 /* AS BaseValue FROM other_table */) AS y
    FROM t AS base
    WHERE Id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT curr.*, GREATEST(prev.Quantity + prev.y, 0)
    FROM t    AS curr
    JOIN rcte AS prev ON curr.Id = prev.Id + 1
)
SELECT *
FROM rcte
```

You were not exactly clear whether the Quantity and BaseValue columns refer to current iteration or previous but the rcte is pretty self explanatory and easy to modify.

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ea25d673f67498576f3f6cc3f59440e8)

Comment: @AdamBaranyai I'm not sure it does work if the `BaseValue` is not the same for all `Id` values https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=822973258134d8a2b40d1f57ccea66ca

Comment: @Nick I didn't test with that, but the `BaseValue` should be the same, as it is derived from a joined table.