# How to perform a sum for all previous records

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

I've been trying to implement the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31767295/11277108) with the added flavour of updating existing records. As an MRE I'm looking to populate the `sum_date_diff` column in a table with the sum of all the differences between the current row date and the date of every previous row where the current row `p1_id` matches the previous row `p1_id` or `p2_id`. I have already filled out the expected result below:

```
+-----+------------+-------+-------+---------------+
| id_ | date_time  | p1_id | p2_id | sum_date_diff |
+-----+------------+-------+-------+---------------+
|   1 | 2000-01-01 |     1 |     2 | Null          |
|   2 | 2000-01-02 |     2 |     4 | 1             |
|   3 | 2000-01-04 |     1 |     3 | 3             |
|   4 | 2000-01-07 |     2 |     5 | 11            |
|   5 | 2000-01-15 |     2 |     3 | 35            |
|   6 | 2000-01-20 |     1 |     3 | 35            |
|   7 | 2000-01-31 |     1 |     3 | 68            |
+-----+------------+-------+-------+---------------+
```

My query so far looks like:

```
UPDATE test.sum_date_diff AS sdd0
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        id_,
            SUM(DATEDIFF(sdd1.date_time, sq.date_time)) AS sum_date_diff
    FROM
        test.sum_date_diff AS sdd1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 
        sdd2.date_time AS date_time, sdd2.p1_id AS player_id
    FROM
        test.sum_date_diff AS sdd2 UNION ALL SELECT 
        sdd3.date_time AS date_time, sdd3.p2_id AS player_id
    FROM
        test.sum_date_diff AS sdd3) AS sq ON sq.date_time < sdd1.date_time
        AND sq.player_id = sdd1.p1_id
    GROUP BY sdd1.id_) AS master_sq ON master_sq.id_ = sdd0.id_ 
SET 
    sdd0.sum_date_diff = master_sq.sum_date_diff
```

This works as shown [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99d0299ffc0ca923f580f37cd647a6d3).

However, on a table of 1.5m records the query has been hanging for the last hour. Even when I add a `WHERE` clause onto the bottom to restrict the update to a single record then it hangs for 5 mins+.

Here is the `EXPLAIN` statement for the query on the full table:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |     table     | partitions | type  |                                                              possible_keys                                                              |                   key                   | key_len |  ref  |  rows   | filtered |                   Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | sum_date_diff | NULL       | const | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                 | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | const |       1 |      100 | NULL                                       |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>    | NULL       | ref   | <auto_key0>                                                                                                                             | <auto_key0>                             | 4       | const |      10 |      100 | NULL                                       |
|  2 | DERIVED     | sum_date_diff | NULL       | index | PRIMARY,ix__match_oc_history__date_time,ix__match_oc_history__p1_id,ix__match_oc_history__p2_id,ix__match_oc_history__date_time_players | ix__match_oc_history__date_time_players | 14      | NULL  | 1484288 |      100 | Using index; Using temporary               |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3>    | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                                                                                                                                    | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL  | 2968576 |      100 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
|  3 | DERIVED     | sum_date_diff | NULL       | index | NULL                                                                                                                                    | ix__match_oc_history__date_time_players | 14      | NULL  | 1484288 |      100 | Using index                                |
|  4 | UNION       | sum_date_diff | NULL       | index | NULL                                                                                                                                    | ix__match_oc_history__date_time_players | 14      | NULL  | 1484288 |      100 | Using index                                |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `sum_date_diff` (
  `id_` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_id` int NOT NULL,
  `p2_id` int NOT NULL,
  `sum_date_diff` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_`),
  KEY `ix__sum_date_diff__date_time` (`date_time`),
  KEY `ix__sum_date_diff__p1_id` (`p1_id`),
  KEY `ix__sum_date_diff__p2_id` (`p2_id`),
  KEY `ix__sum_date_diff__date_time_players` (`date_time`,`p1_id`,`p2_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1822120 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

MySQL version is 8.0.26 running on a 2016 MacBook Pro with Monterey with 16Gb RAM.

After reading around about boosting the RAM available to MySQL I've added the following to the standard `my.cnf` file:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
```

I'm wondering if:

1. I've done something wrong
2. This is just a very slow task no matter what I do
3. There is a faster method

I'm hoping someone could enlighten me!

Comment: Subqueries aren't indexed. You may get an improvement by saving the results of the subquery to a temporary table, add an index to it, then join with the temporary table.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @Barmar - Newer versions (including 8.0) of MySQL will _dynamically_ build an index for a _derived_ table.

Comment: Hi @RickJames - 8.0.26

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...`

Comment: @Barmar - Note the `<auto_key0>`

Comment: I think a faster answer will involve "windowing" functions.

Comment: These are dangerously high; leave them at defaults:

    tmp_table_size=2G
    max_heap_table_size=2G

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670414/mysql-sum-and-min-after-each-operation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425089/is-it-possible-to-index-a-running-total-to-speed-up-window-functions https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268214/how-to-create-a-running-balance-column-based-on-account-number

Comment: The [MySQL windowing functions doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) has examples that are close to what you want. Windowing functions are what you need to lower execution time.

Comment: @RickJames (&Bohemian) - I've read through all the window function material and it's opened up my eyes as to what is possible :) However, I can't work out exactly how to integrate the DATE_DIFF function so as to calculate a sum of all the differences for previous rows. The examples given are much simpler and focus on things like rolling sums which just sum from a frame of previous rows. I need to try and integrate a function that is relative to the current row. Any direction you could give me?

Comment: @Jossy - Would the SUM(diffs) be the same as DIFF(current_row, first_row)?

Comment: @RickJames - I don't think it would. DIFF(current_row, first_row) would only give the difference between the current and first frame row. I need the sum of all the differences between the current row and each of the rows in the frame. If it helps to understand why I need this then the non-MRE version of the query applies a function to the `DATE_DIFF` for each row and then sums all the values. In this way I'm able to create a time weighted count of the number of rows.

Comment: @Jossy - Would you like to provide a small dataset _and_ show what the query should return?

Comment: @Jossy - For starters, the dates are not in a compatible format.  For example, `15/01/2000` should be `2000/01/15`.

Comment: @Jossy - So, some days are counted more than once.

Comment: @RickJames - sorry, built it in Excel and copied across, will amend. For each row then I need the sum of the differences between the `date_time` of that row and the `date_time` of every preceding row (by `p1_id`).

Comment: @Jossy - See `LAG()` or `LEAD()`.

Comment: @RickJames - I started down that road but couldn't figure out how to work in the `SUM` I need as I can't wrap it around a window function. I've now got as far as `DATEDIFF(LAST_VALUE(date_time) OVER (PARTITION BY p1_id ORDER BY date_time RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), date_time)` which gets me the difference between a row's `p1_id` `date_time` and the most recent `p1_id` `date_time` but this isn't what I need and I'm stumped :(

Comment: @Jossy - What is `sum_date_diff` used for?

Comment: Hey @RickJames - thought I'd exhausted your patience :) Thanks a million for sticking with this. `sum_date_diff` isn't used in my 'real' code. I actually apply different types of calculations to each one of the individual differences and then sum these together. An example in semi-pseudo code would be `SUM(POWER(constant, DATEDIFF(current row date, every previous row date)))`. This example gives me a time discounted count of rows. The other calculation variants typically use this discounted count in combo with other current row fields and their corresponding previous row fields.

Comment: @Jossy - Might it be easier to use some function of "how long ago"?  I like an exponential moving average, but it does not take into account "how long" between items.

Comment: Thanks Rick. The challenge as I see it with an EMA is that it assumes you have data points equally spaced in time which mine aren't :( I was really hoping the solution might lie in SQL but from your answer it sounds like I'm going to need to shift everything into Pandas

Answer (score 1):

Whereas it is *possible* to do calculations like this in SQL, it is messy.  If the number of rows is not in the millions, I would fetch the necessary columns into my application and do the arithmetic there.  (Loops are easier and faster in PHP/Java/etc than in SQL.)

`LEAD()` and `LAG()` are possible, but they are not optimized well (or so is my experience).  In an APP language, it is easy and efficient to look up things in arrays.

The `SELECT` can (easily and efficiently) do any filtering and sorting so that the app only receives the necessary data.